# How can I integrate Ethers Wallet with Uniswap Widget

Tags: ethers.js, wallet, uniswap

The application I am working on keeps it's own custom Ethers wallet for each user for signing transactions etc. I wanted to use Uniswap widget for swap function but after a lot of trial and error, but couldn't succeed.

I want the widget to let the user connect to their custom wallets and allow the transactions through their wallet which will be connected to a provider e.g. InfuraProvider/JSON RPC Provider etc. This is just a sample of what I tried to do but widget asks to connect wallet.

```
`  let provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    `https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/${infuraId}`
  );

  async function createWallet() {
    const wallet = ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
    setAddress(wallet.address);

    // Get wallet balance
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
    setBalance(ethers.utils.formatEther(balance));

    wallet.connect(provider);
    setSwap(true);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={createWallet}>Create Wallet</button>
      <div>Address: {address}</div>
      <div>Balance: {balance} ETH</div>

      {swap && <SwapWidget provider={provider} />}
    </div>
  );`
```